# is it bad to have en directory in locale? is there any use for it?

Tags: django, internationalization

the main language is English for my website, some tutorials suggest to use **django-admin makemessages -a**

and others suggest to use **django-admin makemessages -l -de**

but when i use *-a* it make the **en-us** directory as shown below and it seems pretty much useless or is it?
it there any merit for having a **en-us** directory for a website with English as it's main Lang?

or should i just delete  it?

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── some_industry
├── locale
│   ├── en_us
│   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │       └── django.po
│   └── de
│       └── LC_MESSAGES
│           └── django.po
├── machine_request
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── locale
│   │   ├── en_us
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   └── de
│   │       └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │           └── django.po
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── static
│   │   └── machine_request
│   ├── templates
│   ├── urls.py
├── manage.py
└── users
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── locale
    │   ├── en_us
    │   └── de
    └── views.py
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I get this, you could use different language than english in your `msgid`, for example, you could use Russian msgid and English `msgstr`.

If you're using pretty standard option - english `msgid` and `msgstr` in German and you have German language website (no english), feel free to remove `en_US` directory.